# CallBack function from c# to c++

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, dll, callback

I have a C# exe and some vc++ dll's . I am creating a callBackFunction in C# whichh takes structure as its Parameters. My c++ dll will fill this structure and return it back.But 95% of the time My Exe crashes. My dll is multi threaded and my C# has backgroundWorker in it. I have put try catch block to check if any exceptions are coming or not but no exception is being caught. Can any one suggest a better way to send data from my vc++ dll to c# exe

Comment: You need to put in example code.  There are a number of different ways of passing parameters and handling C++ callbacks, any of which can go horribly wrong if done incorrectly.  Be aware also that in spite of what the documentation says, .NET has a habit of garbage collecting managed thunks out from under C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this must work:
(c#)

```
namespace Test
{
    public class CallbackClass
    {
        public void Callback(string s)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(s);
        }
    }
}
```

(c++/cli)

```
...
Test::CallbackClass::Callback(gcnew System::String("woof!");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want you could implement a [COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973800.aspx) Interface, and then you could call the methods from that interface from any .Net client.

Basic [example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/COMBasics.aspx) of implementation.